# find element with value in its array mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having a few issues trying to find one particular element which has a specific value inside its array.

So if the collection holds objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53408df830044f6b43e64904"),
    "_class" : "my.path.Team",
    "name" : "a name",
    "listOfIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("535044b93004ed4738ba3192"), 
        ObjectId("535044b93004ed4738bc3185")
    ],
    "anotherId" : ObjectId("535044b93003ed4738b9317e"),
    "yetAnotherId" : ObjectId("535044a22004ed4738b93101")
}
```

and I need to find one particular element which has a specicific ObjectId inside listOfIds I thought I could use $elemmatch but it doesn't seem to work without the entry inside listOfIds being named something...

I'm using

```
db.team.findOne({anotherId: aVariableInScope.anotherId, listOfIds: { $elemMatch: { aVariableInScope._id }} });
```

But its not working and all the examples I seem to find point to arrays which are structured like:

```
"listOfIds" : [ 
    "value": ObjectId("535044b93004ed4738ba3192"), 
    "value" :ObjectId("535044b93004ed4738bc3185")
],
```

and then you can use:

```
db.team.findOne({anotherId: aVariableInScope.anotherId, listOfIds: { $elemMatch: { "value" : aVariableInScope._id }} });
```

Comment: Can you use `$all` - `listOfIds: { $all: { aVariableInScope._id }}`

Comment: that's not gonna give me what I need. I want to fetch all elements which have in their listOfIds the aVariableInScope._id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the following query:

```
db.team.findOne({
    anotherId: aVariableInScope.anotherId,
    listOfIds: aVariableInScope._id
    }
});
```

According to the **[docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch)**, $elemMatch is only necessary when you're trying to match against multiple fields on an array element. The reason it's saying "expected an object" is that $elemMatch takes a full fledged mongo query (as in, something that you could pass to find) as it's argument.

Comment: True. But it does not restrict the results to the element in the array that matched. Which I believe was the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a single match you can do:

```all-js
db.team.findOne({
    "anotherId": aVariableInScope.anotherId,
    "listOfIds": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "value": aVariableInScope._id
        }
    }
},
{
    "_class": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "listOfIds.$": 1,
    "anotherId": 1,
    "yetAnotherId": 1
});
```

Using the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in order to select the one matching element.

Or for multiples just use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead:

```all-js
db.team.aggregate([

    // Matching documents makes sense to reduce the result
    { "$match": {
        "anotherId": aVariableInScope.anotherId,
        "listOfIds": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                 "value": aVariableInScope._id
            }
        }
     },

     // Unwind the array
     { "$unwind": "$listOfIds" },

     // Actually match the members
     { "$match": {
        "listOfIds.value":  aVariableInScope._id 
     }},

     // Group back again if you must
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "_class": { "$first": "$class" },
         "name": { "$first": "$name" },
         "listOfIds": { "$push":  "$listOfIds" },
         "anotherId": { "$first": "$anotherId" },
         "yetAnotherId": { "$first": "$yetAnotherId" }
     }}
]);
```

More involved but it returns more than one array match unlike what is available to `.find()`.